# Styling textView externally

Tags: android

I have number of text views which have the same attributes only the text changes... I believe there must be an easier way of defining them externally like style.xml or something?

```
        <TextView               
            android:layout_width="250px"
            android:layout_height="100px"               
            android:textSize="13pt"
            android:shadowColor="#000000"  
            android:shadowRadius="1"  
            android:shadowDx="1"  
            android:shadowDy="1"                  
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Look Up"
            android:textColor="#084b7e" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, first of all, you must read this [Applying Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)